# What's the most efficient way to filter values out of a list based on the values in another list

Tags: python

I currently created a list like this:

```
stopfile = os.path.join(baseDir, inputPath, STOPWORDS_PATH)
stopwords = set(sc.textFile(stopfile).collect())
print 'These are the stopwords: %s' % stopwords

def tokenize(string):
    """ An implementation of input string tokenization that excludes stopwords
    Args:
        string (str): input string
    Returns:
        list: a list of tokens without stopwords
    """
    res = list()
    for word in simpleTokenize(string):
        if word not in stopwords:
            res.append(word)
    return res
```

simpleTokenize is just a basic split function on the string which returns a list of strings.

Comment: Are you looking for efficiency or code simplicity? You're not going to get any algorithmic improvements over what you already have, so for efficiency, you'd have to try to do something like reduce the amount of Python bytecode interpretation involved or change `simpleTokenize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine. If you want to do it in a more "Pythonic" way (one line of code instead of 4) you could use a list comprehension:

```
res = [word for word in simpleTokenize(string) if word not in stopwords]
```

Answer (score 2):

You already are using a `set` which is the biggest potential speedup (based on the question title I was expecting your code to have a `list.__contains__` test). The only remaining thing I can suggest is making your function a generator, so you don't need to create the `res` list:

```
def tokenize(text):
    for word in simpleTokenize(string):
        if word not in stopwords:
            yield word
```

Comment: is a set faster than a list for this type of hashtable lookup?

Comment: Yes, `set` membership tests are very fast, specifically because they are hashtables. Python's `list`s are based on arrays, so testing if a value is included in one requires a linear search. That's really inefficient if the list is large, even more so if much of the time you don't find the value (as that means you have to scan the whole list).

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function

```
stopfile = os.path.join(baseDir, inputPath, STOPWORDS_PATH)
stopwords = set(sc.textFile(stopfile).collect())
print 'These are the stopwords: %s' % stopwords

def tokenize(string):
    """ An implementation of input string tokenization that excludes stopwords
    Args:
        string (str): input string
    Returns:
        list: a list of tokens without stopwords
    """
    return filter(lambda x:x not in stopwords, simpleTokenize(string))
```

Comment: `filter` in python is usually significantly slower than a list comprehension with `if` clause.